# Issues with "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

The error occurs at the bottom of the page. I'm currently running Xcode 7.0, and having trouble compiling my code when trying to save an event. I looked at other peoples post with the same questions, but it didn't apply to my code. I appreciate the help!

```
func insertEvent(store: EKEventStore) {
// 1
    let calendars = store.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)
    as! [EKCalendar]

    for calendar in calendars {
        // 2
        if calendar.title == "ioscreator" {
            // 3
            let startDate = NSDate()
            // 2 hours
            let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(2 * 60 * 60)
            // 4
            // Create Event
            var event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
            event.calendar = calendar
            event.title = "New Meeting"
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            // 5
            // Save Event in Calendar
            var error: NSError?
            let result = store.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent, error: &error) // Error is here
                if result == false {
                    if let theError = error {
                        print("An error occured \(theError)")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly?